# Approach to import/load several big JSON files

Tags: json, python-3.x, import

For Python3. 
How would you approach the following problem? (I did not find anything like this in some other post)

I need to open/load 72 different .json files and assign each one of them to a variable. Like this:

```
    import json,
with open('/Users/Data/netatmo_20171231_0000.json') as f:
    d1 = json.load(f)
with open('/Users/Data/netatmo_20171231_0010.json') as f:
    d2 = json.load(f)
with open('/Users/Data/netatmo_20171231_0020.json') as f:
    d3 = json.load(f)
with open('/Users/Data/netatmo_20171231_0030.json') as f:
    d4 = json.load(f)    
with open('/Users/Data/netatmo_20171231_0040.json') as f:
    d5 = json.load(f)
with open('/Users/Data/netatmo_20171231_0050.json') as f:
    d6 = json.load(f)
with open('/Users/Data/netatmo_20171231_0100.json') as f:
    d7 = json.load(f)
with open('/Users/Data/netatmo_20171231_0110.json') as f:
    d8 = json.load(f)
with open('/Users/Data/netatmo_20171231_0120.json') as f:
    d9 = json.load(f)
with open('/Users/Data/netatmo_20171231_0130.json') as f:
    d10 = json.load(f)
```

But I don't want to (also think it is inefficient) perform this for 72 times.
At the end I will create a pandas dataframe, but first I need the json(s) in variables because I'm applying a function to them to flatten the data (these Jsons are very nested).

I also tried to join the JSON files successfully, but the resulting JSON is 5GB, and my PC takes 12 hours to load it. (So this is not an option)

Thanks, and kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@OzkanSener Thanks again for the reply. And for the tip. As you said, First I needed to identify my bottle neck. The bottleneck was in memory consumption. So, the method you suggested did not help so much. Instead I did the following:

```
with open('/Users/Data/netatmo_20171231_0000.json') as f:
d = json.load(f)
data1 = [flatten(i) for i in d]

with open('/Users/Data/netatmo_20171231_0000.json') as f:
d = json.load(f)
data2 = [flatten(i) for i in d]

with open('/Users/Data/netatmo_20171231_0010.json') as f:
d = json.load(f)
data3 = [flatten(i) for i in d]
```

And so on, reusing the d variable instead of creating new ones all the time.
At the end I can create only one big list:

```
from itertools import chain
data= list(chain(data1, data2, data3))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, find out where your bottlenecks are.
If it is on the json decoding/encoding step, try switching to ultrajson
I have not tested it but one way how you could improve is via multiple process.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool

# wrap your json importer in a function that can be mapped
def read_json(pos_json):
    return json.load(pos_json)


def main():
    # set up your pool
    pool = Pool(processes=8) # or whatever your hardware can support

    # get a list of file names
    path_to_json = '/Users/Data/'
    file_list = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]


    list = pool.map(read_json, file_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I think that OP asked about the efficient way to load 72 big json files, not how to assign their filenames to the array (but maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this is not exactly what I'm looking for. The code you suggest only generates a list with the names of the files in the directory. What I want is to create 72 variables, each one containing the data from each Json file.

Comment: @Ptaq666 you are right. I want to know how to efficiently load 72 or even more big json files. Each one in one different variable.

Comment: I edited the code. I have not tested it but good stating point

Comment: @OzkanSener Thanks again for the reply. And for the tip. As you said, First I needed to identify my bottle neck. The bottleneck was in memory consumption. So, the method you suggested did not help so much. Instead I did what I posted in my response.